# Change dimensions of body with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

How can I change the dimensions (width, height) of the body element after the content has been loaded?

Restrictions:

- Only targeting WebKit browsers
- Can't use frameworks like JQuery
- Can't make changes to the original HTML file; only execute JavaScript after the content has been loaded.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.body.style.width = '600px';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `onload` JS event in your `<body>` tag.
For example: `<body onload="ResizeBody();">`.
And the function may look like this:

```
function ResizeBody() {
    document.body.style.width=your_width;
    document.body.style.height=your_height;
}
```

Now it works, sorry for the previous mistake (missing `style` in the tree).

Comment: The question says he can't change the HTML file :)

Comment: The function executes, but the page remains the same no matter what values I use.

Comment: @Nick Craver I can execute javascript after the page has been loaded, though. Will clarify.

Comment: Aaaaargh! I am so sorry! I forgot about the `style` child :) Fixed now. Now my code works (tested).